# Using functions in VBA in MS Word to find/replace strings from an array

Tags: arrays, vba, function, ms-word

I'm relatively unfamiliar with VBA, but trying to write a simple function in Word. The function would run through a list of words and find/replace for each of them within a specific context.

So let's say I have an array of terms:

```
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("if", "then", "next")
```

This following is the VBA code that is created when I create a macro for my find/replace terms. I am adding a paragraph break before every instance of " and VARIABLE " and replacing with "^pand VARIABLE ".

```
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = """ and VARIABLE """
        .Replacement.Text = "^pVARIABLE "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

How would I write something like:

```
for xx in myarray:
  find:    " and ", xx, " "
  replace: "^pand ", xx, " "
```

This seems quite simple if you know VBA, which I don't, so I'm looking for direction. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Here is the working code after applying the commenter's suggestion:

```
Sub ScriptsAnd()
'
' ScriptsAnd Macro
'
'
Dim e

For Each e In Array("if", "then", "next")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = " and " & e & " "
        .Replacement.Text = "^pand " & e & " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Next e
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Dim e

For Each e in Array("if", "then", "next")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = """ and " & e & " """
        .Replacement.Text = "^p" & e & " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next e
```

Comment: Hmm, this didn't do anything when I cut/pasted it into the sub for that macro.

Comment: Your posted code has embedded quotes in the `Text` argument: `""" and " & e & " """`  Does the string you're looking for actually have those quotes ?

Comment: You might also try `With ActiveDocument.Range` in place of `With Selection`

Comment: I think the problem is that I need to replace the ^p with regex/wildcards, because it is not being interpreted by the find/replace function.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix the code and get this working. Thank you for your help!